# matlab for loop to iterate for every 10 steps

Tags: matlab, iteration

I am trying to iterate  every 10 steps in a code using `for loop`.
the code is written below;

```
for i=10:10:30 
 for j=20:10:40
   k=i+j
 end
end
```

So, the first iteration will be `10:20`, then `20:30` and finally `30:40`.But I keep getting errors in my code when i use that.However, if I just typed in `10:20` or `20:30`,it works okay.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Also the first iteration will be `[10, 20, 30]` and second will be `[20, 30, 40]` (note that each element is a single value *not* an array.

Comment: the error i get has to do with my code after the iteration which means whatever it is reading from `k=i:j` is not an array. but from what you just said, it means if i am to put the two (i.e `i` and `j`) together like `k=i:j `  i should get an array for each iteration right?

Answer (score 1):

Having a nested for loop like you have written is not going to yield the results you expect because of the ordering of the loops. If we look at the value of `i` and `j` at the time of assignment of `k`, we'll see the following values.

```
i   j
10  20
10  30
10  40
20  20
20  30
20  40
30  20
30  30
30  40
```

If you want instead for `k` to be equal to `10:20`, then `20:30` and finally `30:40`, then you'll need to do something like this

```
starts = 10:10:30;
ends   = 20:10:40;

% Only use a single for loop
for k = 1:numel(starts)
    k = starts(k):ends(k);

    % Do stuff with this k
end
```